# Running a macro inside a specific date range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that pulls info from several daily log sheets and compiles that info in a master workbook. In the same macro I manipulate the data so that it populates several charts and graphs. The problem that I have is the info would be most usefull if I could establish a date range that I wanted to look at and only pull that data. For exampl if I want to see the amount of scrap created by all machines from 9/9/14 to 11/9/14. Is there a way I could add this to the begining of my already created macro? The info I'm working with looks something like what I have below.

```
Machine     Operator      Date    Production    Scrap
A             w          9/9/14      300          15
B             x          9/9/14      400          0
C             y         9/12/14      150          50
D             z         10/9/14      200          3
```

Comment: where is the macro you created? Please Post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tested.  It will work with a table of changing lengths, and you can adapt the concepts in this to many needs.  Have fun.

```
Sub ScrapCount()

Dim str_dateMin As String
Dim str_dateMax As String
Dim dateMin As Date
Dim dateMax As Date
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim subTotal As Double
Dim lookupDate As Date

Dim lRow As Long

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
subTotal = 0

str_dateMin = InputBox("Input beginning date, mm/dd/yyyy:")
str_dateMax = InputBox("Input end date, mm/dd/yyyy:")
dateMin = CDate(str_dateMin)
dateMax = CDate(str_dateMax)

For lRow = 2 To lastRow

    lookupDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "C").Value

    If dateMin <= lookupDate And lookupDate <= dateMax Then
        subTotal = subTotal + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "E").Value
    End If

Next lRow

MsgBox ("Total scrap for date range = " & subTotal)

End Sub
```

[image: Input1]
[image: Input2]
[image: Solution]

Comment: Although for something like this, I'd probably just define some cells on a "ReportSheet" and have them constantly updating, with a few cells for the Min & Max range.  Maybe a UserForm with a dropdown asking other questions to sort by, or some other added functionality.  This is kind of a conceptual use of VB.  Hopefully something you build on, as opposed to a final solution.

A SumIF statement would probably be alright.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was a big breakthrough for the project I'm working.

Comment: @WesMahoney, if you found something that works for you, and you consider this question closed, feel free to select one of the answers to help future people browsing know it's resolved. :)  http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Very broad but here is what I would go with:

1. Beginning of macro calls a InputBox for date range (1 for start 1
   for end) and stores as date variables)
2. Loop through rows and only
   copy if value of date cell is within range of defined variables from
   step 1